# CSS position sticky - add space between sticky element and parent

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, css-grid, sticky

I've made the following layout for my application:

```
<div class="app-container">
    <header>header </header>

    <main>
        <mat-sidenav-container>
            <mat-sidenav [mode]="'side'" #sidenav>sidenav sidenav sidenav</mat-sidenav>
            <mat-sidenav-content>
                <div class="page">
                    <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">Open Sidenav</button></p>
                    <table-sticky-header-example>loading</table-sticky-header-example>
                </div>
            </mat-sidenav-content>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
    </main>

    <footer> footer </footer>
</div>
```

The block `<div class="page">` is responsible for showing the content. This is also the area, which should be scrollable. Inside this container are often placed tables, which have sticky headers (by using `position:sticky`). Everything is working fine, but i can't find a way to add some space (margin/padding) between the sticky header of the table and the header of my layout without having trouble either with scrollbars or a visual bug.

I've made a little stackblitz, which shows my current implementation/tries:

[Layout without margin or padding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/layout-so)

[Layout with margin](https://stackblitz.com/edit/layout-so-margin) (scrollbar get pushed away from most right position)

[Layout with padding](https://stackblitz.com/edit/layout-so-padding) (adds transparent gap between sticky table header and layout header)

My Questions are:

- Is there a way to add space to my block `<div class="page">` container, so that there will be a gap between my sticky table header and my layout header?
- Can i prevent my scrollbars to get pushed away from the right most position, when i use margin? (padding doesn't work, because the space is transparent, so that my sticky header "floats")

Thanks in advance for every tipp or hint!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a: 'border-top: solid 1rem #ccc;' and some padding top and bottom in 'th' will visually fix it

Comment: Thx for your answer, but I've already tried that - Adding "border-top" moves the scrollbar away from the top, so a gap between the layout header and the scrollbar is visible. So, unfortunately this isn't an option.

Comment: Did you added border-top to the th? cause I've tried that and it worked https://layout-so-i1o8ms.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

Go with the "layout padding" option and simply set the sticky elements `top` to `0 - padding-top` value set on the parent, `top: -1rem;` in this case. This will remove the transparent gap but will also remove the spacing when the element is stuck. If you want to keep the spacing when stuck, look into creating a pseudo-element with the same color background as the table or maybe adding `margin-bottom` or a `border` to the header.